# `_Generic` with a type as output

Tags: c, generics

`_Generic` can select between different statements based on the type of the variable passed, however (as somewhat expected) it fails if these statements contain type names themselves. As an example:

```
#define PROMOTE(var) \ 
    _Generic((var), \
        char: int);

int main() {
   char c;
   PROMOTE(c) i = 0;
   return 0;
}
```

One might expect the above code to work, with the line using `PROMOTE` evaluating to "`int i = 0`", but alas, it does not compile. I tried some roundabout ways to write the type (`int`), such as with a macro (`#define TYPE_int int`) or a typedef (`typedef int TYPE_int`), but to no avail. This is most probably intended (or purposefully undefined) behavior, but I'm still interested in the possibility, even if it requires some C wizardry.

In light of that, how can one make `_Generic` output a type?

*Note: Solutions should rely only on standard C (i.e. no compiler specific constructs).*

Comment: Gcc has 'typeof' extensions, clang supports it as well. It may help here because you could extract a type from a dummy value

Comment: What is your end goal here?

Comment: As for why what you've done doesn't work, the second part of a `generic association` is an `assignment expression`.  It doesn't do token replacement like a macro does.

Comment: @tstanisl Forgot to annotate that the solution should rely on standard C only, thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons The question is the end goal. I do not intend to use this for a specific application (although I think something like this might be quite useful). I simply want to know if the above possible within standard C.

Comment: Re: “`_Generic` can switch between different statements”: No, it cannot. Per C 2018 6.5.1.1 1, a `_Generic` selects between expressions (labeled with types). (Technically, they must be *assignment-expression* in the grammar, which is just any *expression* without the comma operator as its top operator.)

Comment: There is no standard C feature (that is, strictly conforming features—those that are not extensions) that can select between types during program translation (compilation) other than preprocessor `#if` statements and possibly kludges with macro replacements. You can programmatically select a type and create an object of that type by dynamically allocating memory and storing to it with an appropriate lvalue.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think I might be misunderstanding the meaning of "assignment-expression". As I understand it (which is also the result shown by google) it is a statement such as "`int i = 0;`". In this context however, I don't feel like that's the meaning you are using. If that's the case, is there some reference of the meaning of "*assignment-expression*" in this context?

Comment: The C standard uses [Backus-Nauer form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus–Naur_form) or something similar to specify the grammar of the C language. In the various subclauses, a paragraph labeled “Syntax” shows the part of the grammar that the subclause is discussing. The syntax for `_Generic` is shown in C 2018 6.5.1.1 1, and the syntaxes for *expression* and *assignment-expression* are shown in 6.5.17 and 6.5.16. `int i = 0;` is not an expression or a statement; it is a *declaration* (6.7). An expression is also not a statement, although an expression followed by a semicolon is (6.8.3).

Comment: The grammar for `_Generic` in 6.5.1.1 shows that a *generic-selection* is `_Generic` `(` *assignment-expression* `,` *generic-assoc-list* `)`, and *generic-assoc-list* is a comma-separated list of *generic-association*, and *generic-association* is *type-name* `:` *assignment-expression*. That is how we know a `_Generic` selects between *assignment-expression* items. Roughly speaking, an *assignment-expression* is a use of one of the assignment operators, `=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `+=` `-=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, or `|=`. It does not have a type in it…

Comment: `i = 0` is an assignment expression. `i = 0;` is a statement, which is not an expression. (It does contain an expression.) `int i = 0;` is a declaration, which is not a statement or an expression. (It does not contain an expression, except the `0` by itself, or a statement.) You can only have expressions in a `_Generic`, so you cannot have statements or declarations in it.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I can imagine is combination of `_Generic`, compound literals and `typeof` extension available in popular compilers like GCC and CLANG.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct SomeStruct { int x; };

#define PROMOTE(X) typeof(_Generic((X){0}, char: (int){0}, int: (float){0}, float: (struct SomeStruct){0}))

int main() {
    PROMOTE(char) a = 1;
    PROMOTE(int) b = 2.0f;
    PROMOTE(float) c = { .x = 42 };
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%f\n", b);
    printf("%d\n", c.x);
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
1
2.000000
42
```

Unfortunately, This is not standard C.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that relies only on standard C (i.e. can run on any compiler), so I'm not going to accept it. Still +1, as your solution might be useful to someone else going through here.

Comment: @LuizMartins, that's fine. Anyway, `typeof` one of the most popular extensions. See [typeof](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2619.htm#implementation-existing-practice).

Comment: After reading *"the Standard already requires `typeof` to exist [...] any implementation that can process `sizeof("foo")` is already doing `sizeof(typeof("foo"))` internally"*, I find puzzling how this is not already part of the standard. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @LuizMartins the standard requires `typeof` to NOT exist  , the page you quote is being rhetorical

Comment: @M.M So is the source wrong that *"The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand [...]. **The size is determined from the type of the operand**."* implies that any implementation that can compute `sizeof("foo")` is necessarily capable of computing `typeof("foo")`? BTW, the source does not state the standard requires `typeof` to exist, but simply that every compiler can already compute it one way or another, since knowing the type is required to implement `sizeof` (my quoting wasn't very faithful to that, I admit).

Comment: @LuizMartins this is a tautology,  the compiler knows the sizes and types of expressions (otherwise it'd be unable to apply the rules of the language which in many cases depend on the type of the expression)

Comment: @M.M Good point. Now it baffles me *even more* that this is not part of the standard already.